# Developing R package:Note on size of data. have compressed rda file but check() is showing a note on previous size

Tags: r

i am creating R package and i have a data folder having some rda files. i have compressed them by gzip xz methods and the size of file shown in Rstudio side window is also the compressed one and if i open the folder from my laptop the size of rda files is also compressed but if i run check command then it show the previous uncompressed size note

file.info() or file.size also show me the compressed size of file.

resaveRdaFiles(path,compress="bzip2",7,version=2)

i expect output of check() to be data size = 46.5 mb ,but the actual output is 82.9mb

Comment: Hello, Are you developing this package for CRAN? If so you should view their [repository policies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) which state package sizes should not be larger than 5MB.
As for your question, it seems that `check()` is reporting the uncompressed sizes of your rda files. 
All I can recommend is try setting `LazyData: true` in the DESCRIPTION file and also run `tools::checkRdaFiles()` to see what compression is best.
This information was pulled from Hadley's [guide](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) on packages.

Comment: sir i have used checkRdaFiles() . it give me same values that i compressed . if i use lazyData:TRUE is description file than then devtools::check() show me a note on size : 82.9 mb .. but if i change lazyData to lazyDataCompression in description file than devtools::check() give me size note of 46.5 mb which i expected . but by using lazyDataCompression my test get failed by showing some error like object not found ... so because of compression testthat don't work . i don't understand how can i handle such thing. i am developing package for CRAN.

Comment: I can't help you further without knowing more about your code. Almost anything could be giving you this new error. But a bit of advice, when you try to submit to CRAN, you may need to request an exemption for your package size because the upper limit is generally 5MB.